# How to prevent displaying context menu and add a event on right click in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to make a button react different functions between on right/left click event. In a Meteor Event handler I could use "which" to know left/right click, but right click always comes with a context menu of browser, event i set a `event.preventDefault()` in event handler.

I found this code to prevent context menu by google:

```
$('.btn').bind("contextmenu", (e)-> false)
```

it works, the context menu never show, but it stops right click triggering Meteor events also.

Is there a way to remove the context menu and keep left/right click triggering meteor template events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Here is an example for a td in a table. It works the same for a button, just use `.btn` instead of `.dataTable`:

```js
Template.machines.events({
    'mousedown .dataTable td': function(e) {
        if (e.button == 2) {
            console.log("right clicked")
        }
    },
    'contextmenu .dataTable td': function(e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, but not when you try to open a `Modal` while right-clicking. `Template.machines.events({
    'mousedown .dataTable td': function(e) {
        if (e.button == 2) {
         Modal.show('modal',{});
         console.log("right clicked")
        }
    },
    'contextmenu .dataTable td': function(e) {
        return false;
    }
});`

I've verified that the `contextmenu` event handler doesn't get called when the `Modal.show` line gets added in. Weird. This is on Chrome btw. Any ideas?